# Ensure only one goroutine is running using sync.Map

Tags: dictionary, go, concurrency, synchronization, locking

I have a HTTP handler which receives a parameter from query. I don't want to run this handler concurrently for the same query parameter i.e. only one goroutine should be running at a point in time.

This was my idea:

```
import "sync"
import "fmt"

var safeMap = sync.Map{}

func handler(c) {

    _, loaded := safeMap.LoadOrStore(c.param, 1) // loaded is true if value was loaded and false if stored 
    fmt.Println(loaded)

    if loaded {
        c.JSON(http.StatusLocked, "locked")
        return
    }

    go doWork(c.param)

    safeMap.Delete(c.param)

    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, "done")
}
```

But, whenever I send two concurrent requests `loaded` is false for both and both requests are processed. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're starting a goroutine to do the work, then immediately deleting the key, before the work has a chance to complete.  So the chance of lock contention is infinitesimally low.

Why are you using `go doWork()` instead of just `doWork()`?

Comment: Because doWork() takes a long time and I don't want the request to wait. It is more of an async task.

Comment: Then you need to move your lock management into that goroutine, as well.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you do your work (`doWork()`) in a new goroutine. If param is not yet locked, the handler locks it, and launches a goroutine to do the work. But the goroutine serving the request does not wait for the work to complete, it unlocks the param immediately.

Instead do the work in the handler, so unlocking the param will only happen once `doWork()` returns:

```
doWork(c.param) // Note no 'go' keyword
```